# Meteor and angular: adding route from a package

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a project with the "package based project structure". So I created a package for my project core which loads angular and the ui-router. Then I have a package for a feature which depends on the core and adds a route to the project.

the package.js of my core looks like this here:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.2.0.2');
    var dependencies = [
        'ecmascript',
        'templating',
        'angular',
        'angularui:angular-ui-router'
    ];
    var packageFiles = [
        'core.js',
        'scss.json'
    ];
    var clientFiles = [
        'client/app.ng.js',
        'client/routes.ng.js',
        'client/layout.html'
    ];
    api.imply(dependencies);
    api.use(dependencies);
    api.addFiles(packageFiles);
    api.addFiles(clientFiles, 'client');
});
```

and this is the routes.ng.js of my core:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  }]);
```

and thats the package.json of my feature:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.2.0.2');
    var dependencies = [
        'mmintel:mm-core'
    ];
    api.imply(dependencies);
    api.use(dependencies);
    var clientFiles = [
        'client/routes.ng.js',
        'client/home.ng.html'
    ];
    api.addFiles(clientFiles, 'client');
});
```

and thats the routes.ng.js of my feature:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
      $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
              url: "/",
              templateUrl:'home.ng.html'
          });
  }]);
```

However.. I am getting this error on the browser:

```
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

My guess: maybe the path to the home.ng.html is not right, but also "client/home.ng.html" doesnt solve the problem. Is there a trick to get the path? Or is that path correct and my problem comes from somewhere else?

Thanks!

Comment: try to rename home.ng.html into home.html and put all angularjs bindings in the .html document with ng-bind except with curly brackets and try again

Comment: throws the same error except that I also have to wrap my code into <template> tag.. I guess this happens because the "templating" package tries to process this file if there is no .ng in the file name